# No GUI Program for Network(Both for WiFi and Ethernet) {Ocurred after reinstalling some packages}

Tags: wifi, package-management, kali-linux, networkmanager, systemd-networkd

I am using Kali Linux

```
grep VERSION /etc/os-release              
VERSION="2021.1"
VERSION_ID="2021.1"
VERSION_CODENAME="kali-rolling"

uname -v                                  
#1 SMP Debian 5.10.28-1kali1 (2021-04-12)

uname -r                                  
5.10.0-kali7-amd64
```

I accidentally deleted some packages such as  `dnsmasq-base libndpo libnma-common libnma0 libteamdctlo network-managaer`. (since these deleted packages were associated with Network,I was unable to connect internet), But I was able to reinstall it successfully and I was able to reconnect to internet again.But I found that there was no icon of Network(Both WiFi/Ethernet) in task bar,But I was able to connect to internet .( only because it was a saved network)         Output of `ip a`is`wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000`. And Ethernet is also working properly , But I can't see available networks and option to switch the available networks, output of `service network-manager status` is giving `Unit network-manager.service could not be found`. I don't know why it is giving error,before it used to print current status.

I am assuming from above situation that my I have no Program for Network GUI.

I founded some alternates to connect to unknown-WiFi  using terminal, But it's very difficult to connect to wifi (To connect to encrypted WiFi, I would have to manually type the Hexadecimal/ASCII form of the password)

Is there anyway to restore the old Network GUI program, in any ways ?

lastly, **I am not using any external adapters**.

```
Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

Comment: It looks like you also have to reinstall network-manager.

Comment: @berndbausch How to do it ? if I uninstall network-manager I won't have Internet connection to redownload it back?. I mean like I did it back, but it's difficult. So I have to do it again

Comment: I thought you did this earlier. Your words: *I was unable to connect internet, But I was able to reinstall it successfully*. In any case, you don't need Network Manager to use the network. Debian works nicely with the old `ifupdown`, and I would be surprised if Kali were different.

Comment: I mean I did it back , I downloaded the package file in another PC and transferred it to mine  and installed by  `dpkg -i name.deb` . As I told before , When I accidentally removed some packages (specified in the post ), I wasn't able to connect internet  neither with Ethernet nor WiFi. That's why assumed, I needed to have network-manager for  connecting tointernet  Also I run this command  `apt-get --reinstall install network-manager` (which I suppose is to reinstall, I may be wrong) . But this didn't solve my issue

Comment: A few tips for network configuration: https://kali.training/topic/configuring-the-network/.

Comment: @berndbausch After lot of work, finally, It worked with command `nm-applet &` , anyways thanks for the help